# Back propagation, how to deal with one parameter updated twice

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

In my neural network, one parameter (word embedding of some word) will be updated twice. My question is that do I need to update this parameter one by one?  or some other method to update this parameter?

This is the current method I think:

w = w_old + learning_rate * (grad_1 + grad_2)